# maximum packet size for a ping on mac OS X

Tags: macos, size, max, ping, ipv4

I am using Terminal on a mac OS X Lion to ping a particular address. I am unable to send packets greater that ~8400 bytes even with fragmentation. Any reason for this?

Comment: What is it that you're pinging, and what kinds of devices does the ping go through? Could it be that you're pinging some embedded device that may have limited reassembly buffers? Note that the IP specification only requires 576 bytes of reassembly. Have you tried pinging *from* a different computer to isolate the source as the problem?